# Component not re-rendering after setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import Header from './components/Header';
import Bio from './components/Bio';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Photo from './components/Photo';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      name: "John Smith",
      job: "Noob Developer",
      email: "John@Smith.noob",
      university: "Harvard University",
      study: "Law",
      year: "2020",
      experience: ["Google","Facebook","Airbnb"],
      input: false,
    }

    this.switchShow = this.switchShow.bind(this);
  }

  switchShow () {
    this.setState( prevState => ({
      input: !prevState.input
    }))
    console.log(this.state.input)
  }

  render() {


    let {name,job,email,university,study,year,experience,input} = this.state

    return(
      <div className="App">
      <Header/>

      

      <FlexRowContainer>
      <EditButton onClick={this.switchShow}>Edit</EditButton>
      <Photo/>
      <Bio name={name} job={job} email={email} school={university} study={study} year={year} experience={experience} input={input}>
      </Bio>
      </FlexRowContainer>

    </div>
    )
  }
}


export default App;

const FlexRowContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
`
const EditButton = styled.button`
float: right;
width: auto;
height: auto;
position: absolute;
border: transparent;`
```

So I tried to change this.state.input using switchShow method on  and after change the component didn't render even though when I console.log(this.state.input) it succesfully change from false to true or when clicked again it changes from true to false again. Is there anything wrong?

Bio component is down here

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

class Bio extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            name: this.props.name,
            job: this.props.job,
            email: this.props.email,
            school: this.props.school,
            study: this.props.study,
            yearClass: this.props.year,
            experience: this.props.experience,
            input: this.props.input,
        };

    }

    render() {

        let {name,job,email,school,study,yearClass,experience,input} = this.state


        return (
            <div>
            <StyledBioContainer>
                <StyledSubtitle>Name</StyledSubtitle>
                { !input ? <StyledParagraph>{name}</StyledParagraph> : <input></input>}
                <StyledSubtitle>Job</StyledSubtitle>
                { !input ? <StyledParagraph>{job}</StyledParagraph> : <input></input>}
                <StyledSubtitle>Email</StyledSubtitle>
                { !input ? <StyledParagraph>{email}</StyledParagraph> : <input></input>}
                <StyledSubtitle>School</StyledSubtitle>
                { !input ? <StyledParagraph>{school}</StyledParagraph> : <input></input>}
                <StyledSubtitle>Title of Study</StyledSubtitle>
                { !input? <StyledParagraph>{study}</StyledParagraph> : <input></input>}
                <StyledSubtitle>Class</StyledSubtitle>
                { !input? <StyledParagraph>{yearClass}</StyledParagraph> : <input></input>}
                <StyledSubtitle>Experiences</StyledSubtitle>
                { !input? experience.map(experience => <StyledParagraph>{experience}</StyledParagraph>) : <input></input>}
            </StyledBioContainer>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Bio;


const StyledBioContainer = styled.div`
display: flex;
font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
flex-direction: column;
width: 100%;
padding: 3rem;
color: black;
height: auto;
background-color: rgba(0,105,255,.05);
text-align: center;
border-radius: 3px;
margin-top: 1.5rem;
`

const StyledSubtitle = styled.h6`
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
color: gray;
`

const StyledParagraph = styled.p`
margin-top: 0.75rem;
margin-bottom: 5px;
font-size: 20px;
```

Comment: Which component didn't render?

Comment: State changes are async, you can't `console.log` them on the next line and see the change

Comment: @szczocik <Bio><Bio/>

Comment: Can you show us the Bio component?

Comment: @szczocik i Added recently in post above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that in the Bio component, you are assigning the props to the state variables in the constructor and then do conditional render on the state of the Bio. When the components is created, it takes the props and assigns them to the state, but when you change the props, the constructor is never called again.

You can either skip setting the state from props and use props in your render, or if you want to use class component, you can call componentDidUpdate, and update your state with new props.

Here is working example with using props instead of state for conditional render in Bio component

https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-rosalind-8rnih?file=/src/Bio.jsx

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from your `<Bio />` component not listening to props changes to update it's internal state.

You can fix this by adding this to your `<Bio />` component:

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.input !== prevProps.input)
      this.setState({input: this.props.input})
}
```

Here's a full example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vums1a?file=src/App.js

**Edit**: Didn't see @szczocik answer while I was typing mine, but you can also do has suggested and not use a different state in `<Bio />` and use props instead. It will achieve the same result, but you'll lose the local state of `<Bio />` so it really depends on wether you need one in the first place or not.